# How to pass an input variable into another function with python multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

this is what ive tried. im not entirely sure what to do so this is what i have. i just get an error that says 'functiona() takes 1 positional argument but 9 were given' can anyone help? im fairly new to python

```
import multiprocessing

def functiona(inputvariable):
    print(inputvariable)

def functionb():
    inputvariable = input('')

    processes = []

    for x in range(2):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=functiona, args=inputvariable)
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

Comment: And you're also calling `functionb()` inside of `if __name__ == '__main__':`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is your `args` argument to `Process()`. `args` should be a tuple, not a single object. As written:

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=functiona, args=inputvariable)
```

it's causing `inputvariable` to be iterated as the individual characters of the string, which results in `functiona()` receiving multiple arguments instead of just one.

You should specify `args` as a tuple. As you only have one argument, you have to be sure to enter it with a trailing comma, like this:

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=functiona, args=(inputvariable,))
```